# Force a Domain Kerberos Authentication Apache

Tags: apache, authentication, active-directory, kerberos, httpd.conf

I have a website that authenticates users using basic Kerberos authentication from an internal network domain, which is working as intended.

I am running into an authentication issue with users that are connected to my internal network (network A) through a VPN, which are currently authenticated on their computer to a different domain (network B) not being able to log into the website, hosted on network A, with their Active Directory credentials for network A. Even though the username and password are correct for network A, it appears that the domain that is authenticating is not my internal network's domain (A), but the domain for their computer (B).

This is causing the authentication to fail, because it is not requesting access from our AD domain.

This is the authentication part of my httpd conf

```
       <Location />
                AuthType Kerberos
                AuthName "Kerberos authenticated Internet"
                KrbAuthRealms [MY REALM]
                KrbServiceName Any
                Krb5Keytab /etc/httpd/krb5.keytab
                KrbMethodNegotiate on
                KrbSaveCredentials on
                KrbVerifyKDC on
                require valid-user
        </Location>
```

Is there some way to force it to use my local domain (A) instead of the one on the clients windows computer(B)?

Thank you.

Comment: Just don't. Use mod_auth_gssapi.

Comment: Are both domains part of the same forest?